# Sequelize not work in docker (Node + Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, sequelize.js, containers

Even with containers connected to the same network, when executing the migration on sequelize, the error 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND' is returned.

If I remove the host address in the 'database.js' settings, the migration runs but the CRUD routines stop running returning the error "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432"

If I point to the 'postgresdb' container in the 'database.js' settings, the CRUD routines execute but the sequelize migration does not.

Help me please

Fragment of docker network inspect in bridge

```
"Containers": {
            "35467ab419c3632c4c0cfe57e972bd94c7de0a5818e37fdae6eb82a25381ceab": {
                "Name": "api",
                "EndpointID": "d54d95b94bec543fa831526d1abb99346045efc4cc5f4425d5d59b200ece3e62",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7e028bcd80948fd61d14ff87437b963af31291220b7adbc8861fb98a2171f04a": {
                "Name": "postgresdb",
                "EndpointID": "e1d55e0fe8658a142880da27eea12a47d73f6cce472eeff38322ed4d6a60e8ad",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1a:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.26.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  api:
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    depends_on:
      - postgresdb
      - mongodb
      - redisdb
    links: 
      - postgresdb
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgresdb
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/home/node/api
    command: yarn dev
    networks:
      - api
    ports:
      - 3333:3333


  postgresdb:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: postgresdb
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
      - POSTGRES_DB=postdb
    networks:
      - api
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    networks:
      - api
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"


  redisdb:
    image: redis
    container_name: redisdb
    networks:
      - api
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

My database.js file

```
require('dotenv/config');

module.exports = {
  dialect: process.env.DB_DIALECT,
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  define: {
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: When and how are you trying to run the migrations?

Comment: I am trying to execute the migrations right after the containers have been assembled.
When commenting on HOST, the Sequelize CLI returns the following:
'No migrations were executed, database schema was already up to date.'
And a CREATE in Postgres returns the following:
'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432' (in insomnia returns)

Comment: If I uncomment the HOST, the Sequelize CLI will return: 'ERROR: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postgresdb' and CREATE in postgres is executed

Comment: What exact command are you running, and from what context (the shell, a `docker-compose exec` shell, `docker-compose run` an alternate command, ...)?  Or is this being launched by your application itself as part of its startup sequence?

Comment: after starting the containers, I run the Sequelize CLI via terminal in the application directory.
It is a Rest API in Node.
I'm trying to run the application inside a container node that has a mapped local working directory and communicates with database containers, including a postgres container

Comment: From the host and from inside the container are different network environments.  Since your config file depends on environment variables, you can set `POSTGRES_HOST=localhost` from your host shell; it will reach the published `ports:` of the database container.